# Formatted Textboxes for UWP

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

I was wondering if anybody had any recommendations on how I could format a textbox for time inputs(hh:mm:ss) as well as Coordinates in Degrees,Minutes, Seconds (dd°mm'ss"). I am well aware that you can set the format of a string by the String.Format() method.... this does give me the desired layout in the textbox, but I want a control that has the appropriate symbols locked in and will autotab over those symbols as the user gives their inputs.

I have been searching for a way to do this in C#/UWP for a while with no luck, if anybody has any suggestions or could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The **UWP Community Toolkit** has some very good controls which are easy to integrate and one of them is the [TextBox Mask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/extensions/textboxmask) control which is ideal for your scenario.

You can also try out the [TextBoxRegex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/extensions/textboxregex) control which is not quiet what you want but is indeed something you should check out before proceeding.

Please reach out in case you are having difficulty in integrating the control for your specific requirement.

---

Optionally, you can download the sample app for the UWP toolkit to know about all the available controls /Tools. ([UWP Community Toolkit Sample App](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/store/p/uwp-community-toolkit-sample-app/9nblggh4tlcq))

---

EDIT 1:
As you might have noticed, the default behaviour for *tab* is that it sets the **focus** to the next control. Thus, having a single control will not be ideal since on press of *tab*, your textbox would lose focus and you would need to update the text and set the focus back to your textbox.

A relatively simpler way would be the following:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="1">
                <StackPanel.BorderBrush>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{ThemeResource SystemBaseHighColor}"/>
                </StackPanel.BorderBrush>
                <TextBox x:Name="hour" MaxLength="2" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" LostFocus="hour_LostFocus"></TextBox>
                <TextBlock Text=":" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                <TextBox x:Name="minute" MaxLength="2" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" LostFocus="minute_LostFocus"></TextBox>
                <TextBlock Text=":" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                <TextBox x:Name="second" MaxLength="2" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" LostFocus="second_LostFocus"></TextBox>
</StackPanel>
```

[image: Custom control]

This is basically your custom build control/usercontrol. So that when user tabs out it moves to the next textbox inside the stackpanel and so on.

In your `hour_LostFocus` event you can validate the textbox's current value and append 0 and do other validations .

```
private void hour_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{            
            string val = (sender as TextBox).Text;

            Regex regex = new Regex(@"^([0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])$");
            Match match = regex.Match(val);

            if (!match.Success)
            {
                //append 0 and other validations
            }            

}
```

The same applies for minute and seconds .. just that the regex would be different in these cases.

Comment: This control is pretty close to what I am looking for. Do you know if there is a way to an in-textbox tab capability? By this I mean that if my user enters in the number one for the hours section then presses the tab key, they would get pushed to the minutes section of the textbox instead of being pushed to the UWP subsequent control.

Comment: If you use `TextBox Mask` control, the user would not need to use tab to get from the hours to minutes section it happens automatically. For example, the user can simply type 152430 and it will be formatted to 15:24:30 as the user types the characters.

Comment: I understand how the control works. My users may want to type 1 (tab) 5243 so in that case they would 01:52:43. That's why I am asking if there is a way to switch focus to sections within the masked textbox.